# How do I extract unique HTTP links from a Twitter hashtag search?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I want to write a Ruby program that will fetch all the unique http links in the last 100 most recent tweets using the supplied hashtag.

Where should I start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working with gem is okay with you, then, you should have a look at [Twitter ruby gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/).

```
tweets_result=Twitter.search("#tag_to_search -rt", :rpp => 100)
```

It will give you 100 results (excluding retweets, thus maintaining some uniquness).

To display the results:

```
tweets_result.each{|x| puts x.text}
```

Comment: What does :rpp stands for here ?

Comment: Is there any option to exclude invalid links also in the above query ?

Comment: @Metal, if you can filter the 'valids' with some regexp(say), then you can use select enum to filter out valids.

Answer (score 0):

This API call will get the last 100 tweets containing "#ruby".

The entities will contain the URLs

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23ruby&include_entities=true
```

I suggest you read the [Twitter Search Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) and the [Entities Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities).

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved problem. You can use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) directly, or make use of my [Twitter URL Extractor](https://github.com/CodeGnome/twitter_url_extractor), available under the GPL on GitHub.

Comment: Hi, I saw your application. It's good but its test case generates errors and the application also returns invalid urls with the results.

Comment: @metal: MiniTest says `4 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`. So, it definitely works for me and for others. If you can't get it to work by following the README, then a number of answers (including mine) have suggested how you can interact directly with the Twitter API. Good luck!